# What's the best way to store multi-select checkboxes (with the same values each time) in Django (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: django, postgresql

I've got and `Item` and each `Item` should be able to select options from 3 checkboxes, and these checkboxes have the same values between all of them.

I'm not sure on the best way to organise/store this.

It will come back as an array from the browser, `request.POST.getlist('options[]')` so I had been thinking of using a `JSONField`:

```py
options = models.JSONField()
```

But was also wondering if it's better as a `ManyToManyField`? The only thing stopping me there is that it's always the same 3 values, so they'd need to be populated into the database manually.

Any opinions?

[image: checkboxes]

Comment: if number of options won't grow just add 3 boolean fields to your item model

Comment: @WaldemarPodsiadło Ah of course! Thanks!

Comment: Also a bool array will be fine. And you can add more options easily.